# Error al desplegar mi aplicación con GlassFish 5.0, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder.forValue

Tags: web, apache, jsf, netbeans-8.2, glassfish

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con NetBeans 8.2, Glassfish 5.0 y JSF 2.2.
Al crear el archivo beans.xml para la inyección de dependencias y poner todos los `@Inject` Y `@Named` correspondientes me lanza el siguiente error:

> Grave:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder.forValue()Lorg/jboss/weld/util/Function;

Adjunto mi beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.2"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Comment: El glassfish que estas probando es el que bajaste de pagina oficial?

Comment: Si, es el de la página oficial, parece ser que he conseguido solucionar el error por una dependencia de jboss.weld que me faltaba en el pom.xml